# How can I read a Image in .docx and .doc with PhpWord?

Tags: php, phpword

When using PHPWord to read a word file without images, I don't run into any problems.
As soon as it contains an image I get the blank response.

I have tried with code

```
$source = "./62-curriculum-vitae-saisonnier.docx";
$data = "";
$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($source, 'Word2007');

// Adding an empty Section to the document...
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
// Adding Text element to the Section having font styled by default...
$section->addText($data);

// $name=basename(__FILE__, '.php');
$name="docxfile";
$source = __DIR__ . "/results/{$name}.html";

// Saving the document as HTML file...
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'HTML');
$objWriter->save($source);

$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML(file_get_contents($source));
$body = $d->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
$value = $body->nodeValue;

print_r($body->nodeValue);
```

Also, I tried with custom code and still not got the solution.

```
function read_file_docx($filename) {  
  $striped_content = '';  
  $content = '';  
  if(!$filename || !file_exists($filename)) return false;  
  $zip = zip_open($filename);  
  if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;  
  while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {  
    if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;  
    if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;  
    $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));  
    zip_entry_close($zip_entry);  
  }// end while  
  zip_close($zip);  
  $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);  
  $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);  
  $striped_content = strip_tags($content);  
  return $striped_content;  
}
```